# Need to format an object based on another Object data

Tags: javascript, json, object, foreach

Using this Object which is a result from the API ( Columns are dynamic )

```
let json1 ={
    "records": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "Value": "A005",
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Value": "A007",
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "Value": "B001",
        },
        {
            "ID": "4",
            "Value": "B003",
        },
    ],
    "conditional":[
    {"Value":{'A005':'red','A007':'blue','B001':'green'}},
    ]
}
```

I need the below Object to format the data to represent in the UI

```
let json ={
    "records": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "Value": "<span style='color;red'>A005</span>",
        },
        {
           "ID": "2",
           "Value": "<span style='color;blue'>A007</span>",
        },
        {
          "ID": "3",
          "Value": "<span style='color;green'>B001</span>",
        },
        {
            "ID": "4",
            "Value": "B003",
        },
    ],
    "conditional":[
    {"Value":{'A005':'red','A007':'blue','B001':'green'}},
    ]
}
```

Data inside conditional and records are dynamic. 'Value' can be any column name, it can also have any number of columns. All data are dynamic

Comment: Nothing in your question has anything to do with JSON. See [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 2):

We can do it via `Array.forEach()`

```js
let json ={
    "records": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "Value": "A005",
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Value": "A007",
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "Value": "B001",
        },
        {
            "ID": "4",
            "Value": "B003",
        },
    ],
    "conditional":[
    {"Value":{'A005':'red','A007':'blue','B001':'green'}},
    ]
}

// PS: conditional format seems not elegant,especially []
let conditional = json.conditional[0].Value

json.records.forEach(e => {
  let color = conditional[e.Value] 
  e.value = `<span style='color:${color}'>` + e.Value + `</span>`
})

console.log(json)
```

Comment: @Ivar you are right,I am forget it,thanks for your advice

Comment: First of all, Thank you so much for the answer, it works perfectly. What if I have dynamic data inside "conditional"?

Comment: @AnanthKini It can also work with dynamic data,you can update your question